# When is a good time to use an API key over oAuth in an API

Tags: json, api, rest, oauth

We are deciding on standards for APIs at my work.

I've seen some APIs use API keys.  I've seen others use full authentication with username and password (eg oAuth2).

Is there generally a good time to use one over the other?

Comment: oauth never sees the username or password, the consumer just sends and receives various tokens to the service provider until it is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is great for the scenario of "3-party authentication" (1st party: your API server, 2nd party: an app using your API, 3rd party: user on whose behalf the API is used). For example, imagine the Instagram application (2nd party) uploading a photo to the Facebook API (1st party) on behalf of user John Doe (3rd party) to appear on his Facebook wall.

However, many APIs don't have this 3-party scenario - there's just an API and an app, not tied to any end-user-specific information. For example, if a brokerage is providing a stock quote API, it's a two-party scenario because stock quotes are not specific to an end user. (However, if there's an API to access someone's stock portfolio, it's a 3-party scenario).

For 3-party scenarios, OAuth has pretty much become standard at this point. For 2-party scenarios, even though it's possible to use OAuth, in practice simpler authentication schemes are often used (e.g. just an API key in the URL, and use HTTPS to hide the URL from intermediaries).